# RegEx for US Currency Format and length limitation

Tags: regex

I am facing a couple of challenges with regular expressions for US currency.
A quick bit of research on US currency formats led me to the following regular expression which works as wonder.

```
^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?$
```

Depending on my other requirements, I have modified it to the one below. So, this next one is successful in limiting digits after decimal (.) to 10. However, I have a couple more challenges.

```
^[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{0,**10**})?$
```

- I want my RegEx to validate 0.99 & .99 as well. In the above RegEx, 0.99 is validated but .99 is not matched. Hence I updated the RegEx as: `^[0-9]{**0**,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{0,10})?$`

This solved my current problem but now it also matched ,333,323 pattern.

- I have updated RegEx to limit it to 10 deciamls but I also have a requirement to limit it to only 18 digits before decimals(**without US currency delimiter ","**). I tried some patterns but that didnt work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For the second requirement, did you want to remove the comma delimiter entirely or did you mean 18 digits NOT counting the comma delimiter?

Comment: Hi Kash, Thanks for your reply. Comma delimiter should still be in place. But while validating 18 digits of integer part, comma should be omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"*This solved my current problem but now it also matched ,333,323 pattern.*"**
Modified RegEx for this requirement:

```
^((([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*)?)|0)(?:\.[0-9]{0,10})?$
```

***but I also have a requirement to limit it to only 18 digits before decimals(without US currency delimiter ",")***
I am assuming you still need the comma delimiter but want to limit the number of digits before the decimal point to 18 EXCLUDING the comma. Which means you can have between 0 and 5 sets of ",ddd".
Please let me know if this assumption is wrong.
Modified RegEx for this requirement:

```
^((([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:,[0-9]{3}){0,5})?)|0|([1-9][0-9]{0,17}))(?:\.[0-9]{1,10})?$
```

**Update 1:**
Edited the regexes to not match 99,999999.55 as @davidrac mentioned.

**Update 2:**
Edited the regexes to remove leading zeroes

**Update 3:**
All fixes incorporated. Please check if any more left out.

Comment: You latest regex doesn't match 100,111,111.45 - this is tricky :) maybe `^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:,[0-9]{3}){0,5})?(?:\.[0-9]{0,10})?$`

Comment: In addition, I'm not sure if a number with no commas at all should be valid or not -- 1000 should be matched or not?

Comment: @davidrac: thanks David. Edited it again to fix that. Regarding number with no commas, I think the OP needs to have the comma in place based on his initial regex.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David. Yes, the numbers with & without comma's should be matched. That is, 1000 & 1,000 both should be valid.

Comment: Try this `^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:(?:,[0-9]{3}){0,5})|\d{,15})?(?:\.[0-9]{0,10})?$`. I think it fixes all of the issues we've discussed. I'm having fun :)

Comment: It does not match 0.25 :). Morever @Evolving Techie needs both numbers - with and without comma - to be matched, which makes the 2nd requirement more tough.

Comment: To match number's with & w/o comma, I have updated the regEx as follows: ^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:,?[0-9]{3}){0,5})?(?:\.[0-9]{0,10})?$. However, this still doesnt match 0.25 :(. .25 is matched though.

Comment: Hi David & Kash.. I've updated RegEx as follows: ^([0-9]{0,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3}){0,5})?(?:\.[0-9]{0,10})?$. This matches all the patterns I've been testing so far BUT ,333,333.22736

Comment: @EvolvingTechie: This would match leading zeroes too like 00.345 or 0134.243. Try my updated answer for both requirements.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Kash. This is perfect!! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^\d{,3}(?:(?:[^\b],)?\d{3}){,5}(?:\.\d{,10})?$
```

It solves the problem you mentioned, but still this regex has some issues. For example, it allows 99,999999.55 and 0,123.45

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I updated my answer based on this.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*)?(?:\.[0-9]{0,10})?$
```

**explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*)?(?:\.[0-9]{0,10})?$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{1,3}               any character of: '0' to '9' (between 1
                             and 3 times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      ,?                       ',' (optional (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9]{3}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (3 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{0,10}              any character of: '0' to '9' (between 0
                             and 10 times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**some examples:**

```
match : 1,234.45
match : .123
match : 0.12345
match : 123456.7890123
not match : ,123,456.789
```